# Update TextBox content in WPF Window

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm having a WPF Project, in which I'm performing an installation...

To show the installations progress, the window is containing a TextBox which I want to update using for example:

```
LogDisplay.AppendText("Initialising installation..." + "\r\n");
```

This works kind of...

The problem is that the content of the *TextBox* is only getting displayed when the installation is finished.

I have tried now several soluions, such as:

```
/*
LogDisplay.Update;
this.Update();
this.UpdateContent();
*/
```

But non of this was working for me...

The XAML code is:

```
<Window x:Class="Steam_Server_Installer.UI.ServerInstallation"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Steam_Server_Installer.UI"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="" Height="600" Width="900"
        WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen">

    <Grid>
        <TextBox x:Name="LogDisplay" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="470" Width="650" Margin="30,90,0,0" IsReadOnly="True"/>
        <Button x:Name="cancel_button" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,530,115,0" Width="70" Content="Cancel" FontSize="16" Click="cancel_button_Click"/>
        <Button x:Name="finish_start_button" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,530,25,0" Width="70" Content="Finish" FontSize="16" Click="finish_start_button_Click" IsEnabled="False"/>
    </Grid> 
</Window>
```

If someone could tell me a working solution or point me to another question, which already discusses this question, it would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Thanks @rene I will keep it in mind when asking again...

Comment: It sounds like you are running the installation in the UI-thread and that's why your UI is first updated when the process is finished. Try run it in a background thread or use the async/await(/dispatcher)-concept in the finish_start_button_Click event handler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using TextBlock rather than TextBox like this

```
<TextBlock x:Name="LogDisplay" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="470" Width="650" Margin="30,90,0,0" />
```

It would be better to use binding instead of setting it like this. First you will implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` in your .xaml.cs file like

```
public class YourClassName: Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
   public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

   //then create a string variable in your .xaml.cs file like   

    private string _logText;

    public string LogText
    {
         get{ return _logText;}
         set { _logText = value; OnPropertyChanged("LogText"); }
    }

    public YourClassName()
    {
         InitializeComponent();
         //setting data context of the window
         this.DataContext = this;
    }
}
```

And in your XAML, use:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding LogText, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="470" Width="650" Margin="30,90,0,0" />
```

Now, you can just update LogText variable inside your class like

```
this.LogText = this.LogText + "Initialising installation..." + "\r\n";  //or better use StringBuilder and Append function
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer, but since I have never used something like this before, can you explain what you mean with constructor (is it just the part of the code in which I add text to the TextBlock?) and how do I now actually add Text to the LogOutput?... @Ali Baig

Comment: I have updated my answer above and added constructor code, check it out.

Comment: @XaverXor just so you are aware, a constructor in a class is something that is executed when you instantiate an object based on the class. In the example above, the DataContext property gets set on instantiation.

Comment: Thanks again, but now I'm getting the error `"ServerInstallation" enthält keine Definition für "LogText", und es konnte keine LogText-Erweiterungsmethode gefunden werden, die ein erstes Argument vom Typ "ServerInstallation" akzeptiert (möglicherweise fehlt eine using-Direktive oder ein Assemblyverweis).` @Ali Baig

Comment: It will be helpful if you can post it in English!

Comment: Sorry my bad...   It says that 'Server Installation', which is the funktion that is getting called on WindowCreate, is not containing a definition for 'LogText' and that there is no LogText-ExtensionMethod, which accepts a first argument from the type 'ServerInstallation'...@AliBaig

Comment: Have you removed the x:Name="LogText" from your XAML? Please remove that. It could be because of names conflict.

Comment: Yeah I did that already it is exactly what you posted.. And here is the error again in 'clean' English   `'ServerInstallation' does not contain a definition for 'LogText' and no extension method 'LogText' accepting a first argument of type 'ServerInstallation' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)` @AliBaig

Comment: Where are you setting/appending the string? Could you rename your LogText variable name to something else as well and try?

Comment: The basic structure of my code is: At the beginning _ServerInstallation_ is called and calls with `this.GotFocus += new RoutedEventHandler(OnWinLoad);` the funktion _OnWinLoad_ witch calls again the funktion _TTTInsatallation_, where the Installation happens... (Yes unfortunately it needs to be this complex)      In _ServerInstallation_ I have the Code: `this.DataContext = this;     InitializeComponent()     this.GotFocus += new RoutedEventHandler(OnWinLoad);` and in _TTTInstallation_ I use `this.LogText = this.LogText + "Initialising installation..." + "\r\n";` to add the text. @AliBaig

Comment: Make sure `this.DataContext = this;` is after `InitializeComponent()` not before. The exact order should be `InitializeComponent();  this.DataContext = this;`

Comment: Unfortunately it is still not working. I think the problem is that `this.DataContext = this;` is not referring to the public event you are showing in your answer...     And thank you so much that you are helping me  (I know this has to be annoying for you) @AliBaig

Comment: Sorry for not knowing basic thing sagain but do you mean this `public partial class ServerInstallation : Window`? If so of course since it is a WPF-Application @AliBaig

Answer (score 2):

When use long task in UI thread, UI thread is not idle to update other content control.
You must use create other thread and handle task to thread then update the UI control by using the UI thread.

```
1.Create Thread or Task
2.Work task ...
3.Update the UI thread with Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => { TextBox.Text = "text"; });
4.Finish
```